# Increment jQuery variable value doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to create a loop counter which starts from 0 and goes to a value I've defined. So far, I have achieved to make it but only incrementing the variable value by 1 time each. However, when I try to make those increments into 5 or 10 the code doesn't seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var init = $(".po-number").attr("data-from");   
var obj = $(".po-number").attr("data-to");
                  //  set your counter to 1
var increment = 5;  
function myLoop () {          
   setTimeout(function () {    
      console.log(init); 
      $(".po-number").html(init);   
         //  your code here;
      init ++;                    
      if (init < obj) {           
         myLoop();             
      }                       
   }, 1)
}

myLoop();
});
```

I've tried with the +=2 operator and it doesn't work either.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is `.po-number`? does it have the corresponding attributes.. unless you share the respective `HTML`, how do we know..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `init++;` with

```
init += increment; // now it will increment by 5
```

The above is short hand for `init = init + increment;`
And change first two lines to

```
var init = Number($(".po-number").data("from"));  
var obj = Number($(".po-number").data("to")); // now it is number
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The key was to add Number before defining the variables!

Comment: @user2267169 glad to have helped :)